# Hot to get "from pyspark import SparkContext" work

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am not able to successfully execute "from pyspark import SparkContext"

It fails with error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'findspark'

I installed pyspark in anaconda command line using "pip install pyspark" and it has successfully installed.

Can any one help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Question title is misleading. Please show your code

Answer (score 0):

Could you try `pip show findspark`, if it shows no result, just install it by using this command:

```
pip install findspark
```

Reference for `findspark`: https://github.com/minrk/findspark